# Is it possible to configure WiFi device without Apple's "Wireless Accessory Configuration" feature?

Tags: ios, configuration, cellular-network, wifi

I want to configure non-Apple WiFi device using iOS application. Connection would be through WiFi which is created by this same device.

1. Is it best to use Apple's WAC (Wireless Accessory Configuration) feature or is it possible to accomplish it without this? (No need for MFi license then)
2. If it is possible without using WAC: Which would be more time-consuming and expensive, developing the custom solution without WAC or the process(and cost) of getting MFi license?
3. Are there any other disadvantages to deal with if not using WAC?

The caveat here is that while configurating the app also has to access internet through cellular network to get data for configuration. Question about this matter can be found here: [Can iOS application use cellular internet connection while doing "Wireless Accessory Configuration" through WiFi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021976/can-ios-application-use-cellular-internet-connection-while-doing-wireless-acces)

What are your thoughts, experiences on this?

Answer (score 3):

From Apple Developers Forum:

**eskimo**:"

- Is it best to use Apple's WAC (Wireless Accessory Configuration)
  feature …? Yes.  WAC is by far the best user experience here.
- If it is possible without using WAC …
  Yes.  The problem is that the user experience is dire.  It runs something like this:

  1. user runs Settings to switch to your accessory’s Wi-Fi
  2. user runs your app
  3. user enters their home Wi-Fi settings (typically the SSID and password) into your app
  4. your app passes them to your accessory
  5. your accessory tries to join the home Wi-Fi
  6. when your accessory shuts down its own AP, iOS should switch back to the home Wi-Fi

And that’s the best case scenario.  If something goes wrong, like the user mistypes their password, the process can be a lot more confusing.
There are steps you can take to improve this but the reality is that it will never be as smooth as it is with WAC.

- Are there any other disadvantages to deal with if not using WAC? I
  think the above is sufficient, eh?"

Comment: Hi! Haven't actually implemented it yet.

Comment: Thanks for your response Roland.

Comment: Hello @Ushan87. Unfortunately no, this project didn't go into work yet.

Comment: So if i understand correctly the only purpose of WAC mode is to connect the external device to WiFi. If the device has an inbuilt mechanism to connect to the Wifi then there is no need for the MFi certification. Can anyone clarify on this ?